Writing to `CONOUT$` on Windows for node.js 22
I am trying to fix a node.js package that writes directly to the console (/dev/tty in Unix-likes) in the case of Windows. It's using some internal bindings, sadly, which means it breaks with different Node.js versions, but I am able to get it working with node 18 and 20:
  // vX.X.X
  const nodeVersion = parseInt(process.version.split('.')[0].slice(1), 10)
  const openArgs = [
    "CONOUT$",
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
    fs.constants.O_RDWR | fs.constants.O_EXCL,
    0o666
  ];

  if (nodeVersion < 20) {
    // Older version of node require null being passed explicitly for the
    // optional arguments, but this breaks node 20.
    openArgs.push(null, null)
  }

  return new tty.WriteStream(
    process.binding("fs").open(...openArgs)
  );

However, in node 22, it appears that CONOUT$ is not available for opening:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\myproject\CONOUT$'

Does anyone know how opening "special" files like this on Node 22 can be accomplished? Better yet, does anyone have a less hacky way to write directly to the console? The original author does not want to just use stdout due to them wanting to reserve it for piping output.
